# Perl Difference between <FH> and <$FH>

Tags: perl

I am not new to Perl by any stretch, but I have actually been away for several years.

Upon my 'return,' lurking on this site and others, I can't help but notice where I used to do this:

```
open IN, 'filename.txt' or die;
open OUT, '>filename.new' or die;
while (<IN>) {
  print OUT
}
close OUT;
close IN;
```

I now see that the standard approach is to now do this:

```
open my $IN, '<', 'filename.txt' or die;
open my $OUT, '>', 'filename.new' or die;
```

I am a big fan of "when in Rome," and I endeavor to do the things the correct way.  On that note, is my first approach wrong?  Does it have implications or risks I'm not aware of?

Off hand one drawback to approach #1 is that this will compile (and probably run) in Perl, even with strictures turned on:

```
open IN, 'filename.txt' or die;
open OUT, '>filename.new' or die;
while (<NOT_EVEN_CLOSE>) {
  print OUT
}
close OUT;
close IN;
```

Another possible (?) reason is you can pass `$IN` as a parameter?  Kind of like the difference between a static class and a singleton?  I'm grasping for straws on that one.

Finally, assuming method 2 is more correct or better, should I go back and modify old code to apply this change in methodology?

Also, it's quite possible that in my heavy days of doing Perl I was still under a proverbial rock, so if this is a decade old convention, please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` refers to `*IN` which refers to the symbol `IN` in the current package. It is global.

`my` creates variables that are lexically scoped.

Restricting the scope of a variable to where it's needed is a fundamental aspect of CS.

It also allows `use strict;` to find typos.